# Continue Docstring in New Line in Rust and VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

Consider the struct as below:

```rust
struct Foo;
```

I'd like to write some docs for it, so I do:

```rust
/// whatever
struct Foo;
```

However, when I press enter, it creates a blank line:

```rust
/// whatever

struct Foo;
```

Instead of a new line continuing the docstring, prepending `///` to it:

```rust
/// whatever
///
struct Foo;
```

I haven't touched computer or done programming for 6 months. I remember I could do that 6 months ago. Maybe it's because I had an extension (maybe, RLS?) invoking that behavior 6 months ago and I do not have it right now.

How can I continue docstrings in newlines in Rust and VSCode?

---

**VSCode and Extensions**

- VSCode 1.53.0
- Rust Extensions (Pack) 0.0.3
- Rust 0.7.8
- Rust Analyzer 0.2.481

**Other**

- rustc and cargo 1.49.0
- rust-analyzer (provided by Rust Analyzer extension) commit 336909b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature does exist in rust-analyzer, but it needs to be enabled explicitly. To enable it, you need to add the following to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
   "key": "Enter",
   "command": "rust-analyzer.onEnter",
   "when": "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible && editorLangId == rust"
}
```